# Google plus integration in moodle

Tags: google-api, moodle

I have done the google api integration in moodle using gsaml. But i have an issue. Every thing works fine. But google plus doesnot work. Google plus only works if i first sign into gmail. I am trying to use hangout feature. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in view did load where you want to show google+ sign button

```
self.signInButton_google = [[GPPSignInButton alloc]init];
self.signInButton_google.frame = //pass button frame
[self.view addSubview:self.signInButton_google];

google_signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
google_signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
google_signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;

google_signIn.clientID = kClientId;
google_signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];
google_signIn.delegate =self;
```

Comment: ,.. Acutally I have added google api in moodle using gsaml. Gmail works for sso but gplus doesnot. Gplus only works if i first sign into the gmail account. I donot need to add a separate button to gplus.